# Обратимая операция xor

Tags: reverse-engineering

Здравствуйте! Есть такая задачка. Есть три значения `a`, `b`, `c`. изначально все значения известны и `c` это ключ (все значения в двоичной системе счисления). Скажите, как из этих 3 значений получить 1 в двоичной системе счисления? Может есть какие-то обратимые `xor` башни или что-то ещё?

Вот к примеру:

```
a = 0100;  
b = 1010;  
c = 0111;  

a xor b xor c = d;
```

Как из `d` зная `c` получить `a` и `b`?

Нужны любые варианты, либо же объясните, почему нельзя придумать что-то подобное?

И как же насчёт XOR gate и такого подобного? Если вариантов вообще 0, предложите какой-то свой вариант, может можно как-то задачку немного переписать. Но условие, что в конце a,b неизвестны, так и остаётся.

Comment: никак. Сами подумайте) У вас есть a^b как отсюда найти a

Comment: xor не сильно отличается о т обычных арифметических операций. вспомним школу  `x+y+5=21` => `x+y=21-5=16` сколько вариантов x и y у нас есть ? правильно, бесконечное множество, если не известно дополнительных условий

Comment: "a xor b xor c" я привёл для примера, знаю есть различные XOR башни и похожее, где можно с 3 значений получить 1, но можно с таких ли получить обратно 3 значения? Нужен любой рабочий вариант.

Comment: Нет, конечно. Все сведется к получению `a`, `b` из уравнения `a^b=c` при известном `c`. Это уравнение имеет бесконечно много решений. Т.е. по сути у вас есть система линейных уравнений, соответственно, условий должно быть не меньше неизвестных.

Comment: `И как же насчёт XOR gate и такого подобного?` причем здесь логические вентили? Задача не имеет решения. Представьте, что `a` + `b` = `600`, назовите `a` и `b`.

Comment: Очень похоже на то, что твой вопрос неверно поняли, попробуй расписать более подробно что у тебя есть и что ты хочешь получить?

Comment: Кратко говоря, a b c это значение с 0 и 1, нужно получить 1 целое значение, при этом в конце я знаю c и результат трёх значений.. Получается нужно что-то типо сжатия значений для двоичной системы счисления.

Comment: А что такое "xor башня", гугл такого термина не находит

Answer (score 1):

Предположим `c == d == 1`. Тогда `a xor b == 0`. В результате имеем, вообще говоря, бесконечно много пар `a, b` (`0,0`, `1,1`, любая пара при `a==b`). Отсюда ясно, что задача решения не имеет.

Comment: А как же насчёт xor башни и такого подобного? И предложите, пожалуйста, какой-то свой вариант решения и модернизации задачи(если это будет необходимо).